# Set User Agent with HTTPClient Gem

Tags: ruby, http, rubygems

Recently I begun a small project which involves logging into a website and fetch new messages from my inbox. Since I've already done sone stuff with httpclient I just went with it and it worked great.
However I need to set the user agent and that's where my problem appeared. I wanted to set it to a special string, however httpclient seems to append a string containing the gem and ruby version(2.4.0, ruby 2.0), except when I set it to nil.

Is is possible to set the user agent without appending this?

Comment: Have you tried the Unirest gem; its an elegant implementation. You may be able to pick it up very easily. http://unirest.io/ruby.html

Comment: I've heard of it, might give it a try :-). Does it have the same cookie support as httpclient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could solve it with the help of the developer. Just use this code:

```
HTTPClient.new(default_header: {"User-Agent" => "#{your_user_agent_in_here"})
```